# wxWigets fails to pass events (or anything) from inside a wxGridSizer if there is a panel or wxScrolledWindow

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

In wxWidgets 3.0.4 compiled with Visual-C++ 2010 Express. In the main frame if I create a wxGridSizer directly and add to the sizer it works fine, but if instead wxBoxSizer -> wxScrolledWindow -> wxGridSizer it does not interact with whatever inside, including events.

It all began with a panel inside the wxBoxSizer that you insert as many as you need (before you see how many columns/rows are needed). The idea is to have wxScrolledWindow take care if not fit in one screen.
I have tried many, many things and look in the Internet. To make it easy and to the minimum that shows the behavior I will show code inside a frame (with menu and menubar that I do not show to point to the problem) that adds a checkbox, the easiest thing I can think of. No connects, no nothing to the checkbox. Without the wxScrolledWindow you can check it, with the wxScrolledWindow you cannot.
I have tried with a panel instead wxScrolledWindow, with events, with more things.. and the same behavior.
Any idea? Thank you in advance.

WORKS:

```
    grid = new wxGridSizer( 3, 2, 0, 0 );  //declared in the class
    wxCheckBox *prueba_cbox = new wxCheckBox( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Check Me!"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    grid->Add( prueba_cbox, 0, wxALL, 5 );
    grid->Fit(this);
    this->SetSizer(grid);
    this->Layout();
    this->Centre( wxBOTH );
```

DO NOT WORKS:

```
    misizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxScrolledWindow* miscroll = new wxScrolledWindow(this, wxID_ANY);
    miscroll->SetScrollRate( 0, 16 );
    misizer->Add(miscroll, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 0);

    grid = new wxGridSizer( 3, 2, 0, 0 );

    wxCheckBox *prueba_cbox = new wxCheckBox( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Check Me!"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    grid->Add( prueba_cbox, 0, wxALL, 5 );
    grid->Fit( miscroll );
    miscroll->SetSizer( grid );

    misizer->Fit(this);
    this->SetSizer( misizer );
    misizer->Layout();
    this->Layout();
    this->Centre( wxBOTH );
```

More, in: "misizer->Add(miscroll, 1, wxALL | wxEXPAND, 0);"

Depends on the border, with 10 or more works, with 5 or less does not work. In this easy example; when actually putting panels inside, the events do not work even with a border of 120.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU you want to have the following layout:

`wxFrame` -> `wxBoxSizer` -> `wxScrolledWindow` -> `wxGridSizer` -> `wxCheckBox`

So far it is nothing wrong with the `wxGridSizer`, but with the parent of `prueba_cbox` which should be `miscroll` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

wxCheckBox *prueba_cbox = new wxCheckBox( this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Check Me!"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );

should be a child of miscroll, not of this (the frame).

Thank you (and sorry for the stupid  question)